# How to split date by Python

Tags: python

I have the date like below.

```
7/1 09:00
7/1 12:00
7/1/19 12:00
7/2/19 13:00
7/3 4:00*
```

And I want to split this date only to get date without the time and year.

```
7/1 
7/1 
7/1
7/2
7/3
```

I m thinking of using lambda function. But I'm not sure how to use this.

```
order['orderDate'] = train.date.apply(lambda x : x.split).astype('int')
```

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: I think you should add pandas tag also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
 train.date.str.extract(r'(\d+/\d+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
train.date.str.extract(pat=r'^(\d+/\d+).*').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda` like this,

```
order['orderDate'] = train.date.apply(lambda x : '/'.join(x.split('/')[:2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your input constraints, if your input is plaintext, consider the regex 
`re.findall(r'^\d+/\d+', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)` which looks for "digits, a slash, and then more digits, at the start of a line".  The `flags` is there to tell your regex engine that `^` is the start of every line, not the start of the whole text.